# Why I'm unable to properly authenticate with Google?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

So I'm new to react and I'm trying to authenticate with Google. The problem is every time I try to log in or signup with Google Authentication I'm shown a blank screen with some errors in the console.
This is my App component from where the error originates. The error based on userlocation hook,I guess. Initially, I was getting an error telling me that the location variable is undefined and I fixed that by moving by Router tags in index.js file and it worked. But, now again, its causing error.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import {SignUp,Login,Sidebar,Navbar,Profile} from './components'
import {ResetPassword} from './pages'
import {ResetPasswordConfirm} from './pages'
import {Activate} from './pages'
import {PrivateRoute} from './components'
import {load_user,checkAuthenticated,logout,googleAuthenticate} from './actions/auth'
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {Upload,ClassDiagram,Table,Buttons,Saved} from './pages'
import axios from 'axios'
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'
import queryString from 'query-string'
function App({checkAuthenticated,
  load_user,isAuthenticated,
  userdata}) {

    let location = useLocation()
    
    const [darkmode,setDarkmode] = useState(false);
    const [sidebar,setSidebar] = useState(true)
    
  
    const showSidebar = ()=> {setSidebar(!sidebar)}
    

    const applyDark = () => {

      let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/update/${userdata?.id}/`;

        async function setDarkTheme(){
        
          const resp = await axios.patch(url,{"darktheme":!darkmode})
          setDarkmode(!darkmode)
             
      } 
      
      setDarkTheme()
      
    }

    
  
  useEffect(() => {
      const values = queryString.parse(location.search)
      const state = values.state? values.state : null
      const code = values.code? values.code : null
      console.log(state)
      console.log(code)
      if(state && code){
        googleAuthenticate(state,code)
      }
      else{
        checkAuthenticated();
        load_user();
      }

     
      
  }, [location]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (isAuthenticated){
      let url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/get/${userdata?.id}/`;

      async function getDarkTheme(){
      
        const resp = await axios.get(url)
        setDarkmode(resp.data.darktheme)           
    }  

        getDarkTheme()
    }
  })

  
  
  return (
    
    
<div>
    {isAuthenticated && 

    <div className={darkmode?"darkmode":"light"}>
        {userdata?
          <div>
        <Navbar showSidebar={showSidebar}
        fullname={userdata.fullname} 
        darkmode={darkmode}/>

        <div className="dashboard">

            <Sidebar sidebar={sidebar}
            fullname={userdata.fullname}
            setDarkmode={applyDark}/>
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/profile' 
            component={() => <Profile darkmode={darkmode} userdata={userdata}/> } />

            <Route exact path='/scanner' component={Upload} />
            <Route exact path='/buttons' component={Buttons} />

            <Route exact path='/cd' 
            component={() => <ClassDiagram darkmode={darkmode} id={userdata.id}/> } />

            <Route exact path='/sv'
            component={()=><Saved id={userdata.id}/>} />

            <Route exact path='/table' 
            component={()=><Table darkmode={darkmode} id={userdata.id}/>} />
            
            <Route exact path='/buttons' component={Buttons} />
          </Switch>
      </div>
      </div>:<h1>Loading</h1>}
      </div>
     }

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route exact path='/reset-password' component={ResetPassword} />
        <Route exact path='/password/reset/confirm/:uid/:token' component={ResetPasswordConfirm} />
        <Route exact path='/activate/:uid/:token' component={Activate} />
      </Switch>
      
      
    
      </div>
   
  );
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
  userdata: state.auth.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {checkAuthenticated,load_user,googleAuthenticate})(App)
```

This is the image of the error shown in the console. Please guide.
[The Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOFxO.jpg)

The code for index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {DataProvider} from './DataContext'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import configureStore from './store';
const { persistor, store } = configureStore()

ReactDOM.render(
  
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
    <DataProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </DataProvider>
    </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: What is `useLocation` hook doing here? Can you share the code? And can you see what is the value of `location` before you start using it?

Comment: @Penguin I printed its value on the console. Before I start using it, its value is null.

Comment: Ok. can you share `useLocation` code to understand why it is returning null value.

Comment: useLocation is a hook I'm using. Its not a seperate component

Comment: @Penguin , the main reason to use useLocation hook is to extract state and code from the url whenever user tries to authenticate with google. After extracting those state and code, these are passed to googleAuthenticate method as shown in the code to authenticate with Google.

Answer (score 0):

A few things missing here to debug your code.
For a start, make sure you wrap your Router around your App.js like this:

```
 import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
 
   <BrowserRouter>
         <App />
     </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I've done this in my index.js file. And still getting the error

Comment: please post your imports as well as your index.js

Comment: @Kirley, added the index.js file and imports. You can check

Comment: No clue, so far..
Try adding   `<Route exact path="/" component={App} />` into your index.js file instead of     `<App />`
Also replace `[location]` on `line 61` with `[checkAuthenticated, load_user, location]` to not miss any dependencies